# Authentication Error when trying to access a gmail business account to read emails - using IMAP_4SSL

Tags: python, gmail-imap

I am trying to access a gmail account so I can read emails and save PDFs attached to those emails. I wrote the code and it works fine when I tested it on my personal gmail account (something@gmail.com), but now that I am trying to do it for this new address (reporting@company.com, which is a gmail business account) my code isn’t working to even connect.

I get an error message saying

```
Error: b’[AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] Invalid Credentials (Failure)’
```

I know the login email and the password are both correct. I have already downloaded the credentials.json file from the Google API page.

My code is as below:

```
Mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(“imap.gmail.com”)
Mail.login(“reporting@company.com”,’password’)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're still using a password in your code, then you need to get your users to [enable Less Secure Apps](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255), or if they're using 2-Step Verification, [create an App Password](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833).

However, a better approach would be to use OAuth instead of a password. If you've downloaded the credentials.json file from the Google Developers Console, you already did the first step. :) Google has [a guide to use OAuth with IMAP in Python](https://github.com/google/gmail-oauth2-tools/wiki/OAuth2DotPyRunThrough), as well as [a code sample](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/google/gmail-oauth2-tools/master/python/oauth2.py) (see the `TestImapAuthentication` method there).

Comment: Thank you for the response! 
This turned out to be a case where I had to enable 2-step authentication on the Google account.

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do was enable 2-step authentication on the google account.